# Using swig for python list input and output

Tags: python, c, swig, typemaps

I am using SWIG to build a Python module for some functions' evaluation based on their C code.

The main function I need is defined as follow:

```
void eval(double *x, int nx, int mx, double *f, int func_id)
```

And the aimed python function should be:

```
value_list = module.eval(point_matrix, func_id)
```

Here, `eval` will call a benchmark function and return their values. `func_id` is the id of function eval going to call, `nx` is the dimension of the function, and `mx` is the number of points which will be evaluated.

Actually, I did not clearly understand how SWIG pass values between typemaps (like, `temp$argnum`, why always using `$argnum`?). But by looking into the wrap code, I finished the `typemap.i` file:

```
%module cec17

%{
#include "cec17.h"
%}

%typemap(in) (double *x, int nx, int mx) (int count){
        if (PyList_Check($input)) {
                $3 = PyList_Size($input);
                $2 = PyList_Size(PyList_GetItem($input, 0));
                count = $3;
                int i = 0, j = 0;
                $1 = (double *) malloc($2*$3*sizeof(double));
                for (i = 0; i < $3; i++){
                        for (j = 0; j < $2; j++){
                                PyObject *o = PyList_GetItem(PyList_GetItem($input, i), j);
                                if (PyFloat_Check(o))
                                        $1[i*$2+j] = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
                                else {
                                        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "list must contrain strings");
                                        free($1);
                                        return NULL;
                                }
                        }
                } 
        } else {
                PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "not a list");
                return NULL;
        }
}

%typemap(freearg) double *x {
        free((void *) $1);
}

%typemap(in, numinputs=0) double *f (double temp) {
        $1 = &temp;
}

%typemap(argout) double *f {
        int i = 0;
        int s = count1;
        printf("pass arg %d", s);
        $result = PyList_New(0);
        for (i = 0; i < s; i++){
                PyList_Append($result, PyFloat_FromDouble($1[i]));
        }
}

void eval(double *x, int nx, int mx, double *f, int func_num);
```

However, strange things happened then. Usually, I test 30 dimensional functions. When evaluating less than 10 points (`mx` < 10), the module works fine. When evaluating more points, an error occurs:

```
[1] 13616 segmentation fault (core dumped) python test.py
```

I'm quite sure the problem is not in the c code, because the only place where 'mx' occurs is in the 'for-loop' line in which are evaluations of each point.

I also tried to read the wrap code and debug, but I just can't find where the problem is. Following is a part of the wrap code generated by SWIG, and I added a 'printf' line. Even this string is not printed before the error.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_eval(PyObject *SWIGUNUSEDPARM(self), PyObject *args) {
  PyObject *resultobj = 0;
  double *arg1 = (double *) 0 ;
  int arg2 ;
  int arg3 ;
  double *arg4 = (double *) 0 ;
  int arg5 ;
  int count1 ;
  double temp4 ;
  int val5 ;
  int ecode5 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj0 = 0 ;
  PyObject * obj1 = 0 ;
  printf("check point 0");  
  {
    arg4 = &temp4;
  }
  if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args,(char *)"OO:eval",&obj0,&obj1)) SWIG_fail;
  {
    if (PyList_Check(obj0)) {
      arg3 = PyList_Size(obj0);
      arg2 = PyList_Size(PyList_GetItem(obj0, 0));
      count1 = arg3;
      int i = 0, j = 0;
      arg1 = (double *) malloc(arg2*arg3*sizeof(double));
      for (i = 0; i < arg3; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < arg2; j++){
          PyObject *o = PyList_GetItem(PyList_GetItem(obj0, i), j);
          if (PyFloat_Check(o))
          arg1[i*arg2+j] = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
          else {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "list must contrain strings");
            free(arg1);
            return NULL;
          }
        }
      } 
    } else {
      PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "not a list");
      return NULL;
    }
  }
  ecode5 = SWIG_AsVal_int(obj1, &val5);
  if (!SWIG_IsOK(ecode5)) {
    SWIG_exception_fail(SWIG_ArgError(ecode5), "in method '" "eval" "', argument " "5"" of type '" "int""'");
  } 
  arg5 = (int)(val5);
  eval(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5);
  resultobj = SWIG_Py_Void();
  {
    int i = 0;
    int s = count1;
    resultobj = PyList_New(0);
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++){
      PyList_Append(resultobj, PyFloat_FromDouble(arg4[i]));
    }
  }
  return resultobj;
fail:
  return NULL;
}
```

The problem seems a little tedious. Maybe you could just show me how to write the proper `typemap.i` code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your evaluation function is supposed to do, so I took a guess and implemented a wrapper for it.  I took `value_list = module.eval(point_matrix, func_id)` to mean you want to return a list of result of evaluating some function against each row of data points, and came up with the following.  Things I changed:

1. The typemaps replace the first *four* parameters with a Python list of lists of numbers.
2. space for the results in `f` was malloced.
3. To accept other numeric types except `float`, `PyFloat_AsDouble` was called on each value, and `PyErr_Occurred` was called to see if it failed to convert.
4. The `freearg` typemap now frees both allocations.
5. The `argout` typemap now handles the `f` output parameter correctly.
6. I added a sample `eval` implementation.

   ```
   %module cec17

   %typemap(in) (double *x, int nx, int mx, double* f) %{
       if (PyList_Check($input)) {
           $3 = PyList_Size($input);
           $2 = PyList_Size(PyList_GetItem($input, 0));
           $1 = malloc($2 * $3 * sizeof(double));
           $4 = malloc($3 * sizeof(double));
           for (int i = 0; i < $3; i++) {
               for (int j = 0; j < $2; j++) {
                   PyObject *o = PyList_GetItem(PyList_GetItem($input, i), j);
                   double tmp = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
                   if(PyErr_Occurred())
                       SWIG_fail;
                   $1[i * $2 + j] = PyFloat_AsDouble(o);
               }
           }
       } else {
           PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "not a list");
           return NULL;
       }
   %}


   %typemap(freearg) (double *x, int nx, int mx, double* f) %{
       free($1);
       free($4);
   %}

   %typemap(argout) (double *x, int nx, int mx, double* f) (PyObject* tmp) %{
       tmp = PyList_New($3);
       for (int i = 0; i < $3; i++) {
           PyList_SET_ITEM(tmp, i, PyFloat_FromDouble($4[i]));
       }
       $result = SWIG_Python_AppendOutput($result, tmp);
   %}

   %inline %{
       void eval(double *x, int nx, int mx, double *f, int func_num)
       {
           for(int i = 0; i < mx; ++i) {
               f[i] = 0.0;
               for(int j = 0; j < nx; ++j)
                   f[i] += x[i*nx+j];
           }
       }
   %}
   ```

Output:

```
>>> import cec17
>>> cec17.eval([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],99)
[6.0, 15.0]
```

Error checking could be improved.  For example, checking for sequences instead of lists.  Only the outer list is checked that it actually is a list, so if `[1,2,3]` was the first parameter instead of nested lists, it won't behave properly.  There is no check that all the sublists are the same size, either.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: @逸峰李 If my answer is useful, consider upvoting and accepting :)